# Replace sub-string javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, ecmascript-6, replace, substring

I need to replace just substring from string matches my regex.

```
const text = "There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available,

<a href='https://stackoverflow.com/'>stackoverflow</a>

but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humor, or randomized words which 

<a href="/page2">page 2</a>

don't look even slightly believable.
If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text.
All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the";
```

I need to add a target blank for all external hyperlinks to be like

```
const text = "There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available,

<a target='_blank' href='https://stackoverflow.com/'>stackoverflow</a>

but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humor, or randomized words which 

<a href="/page2">page 2</a>

don't look even slightly believable.
If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of the text.
All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the";
```

Comment: "_I need to convert all external hyperlinks in this text to be ......_" to be what?

Comment: I edited the question, <a href='https://stackoverflow.com/'>stackoverflow</a>
to be <a target='_blank' href='https://stackoverflow.com/'>stackoverflow</a>

Comment: Maybe: https://regex101.com/r/5BfZXV/1

Comment: See my update for a version that handles full URLs for local links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many issues here

1. JavaScript strings cannot have newlines, template literals can (see later)
2. Javascript string that are in one kind of quotes needs the same kind of quotes escaped, i.e. `"this is not "possible""` but `"this is \"possible\""`
3. You do NOT want to regex on your HTML

Here I take all links that start with http and set the target

I ASSUME you do not have links like `a href="http_is_a_protocol.html"`
If you might have that, then you need to use a more clever selector or see my second version

```js
// Here I use a template literal backtick to contain newlines and quotes
const text = `There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available,

<a href='https://stackoverflow.com/'>stackoverflow</a>

but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humor, or randomized words which 

<a href="/page2">page 2</a>

don't look even slightly believable.
If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text.
All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the`;

const div = document.createElement("div")
div.innerHTML = text;
[...div.querySelectorAll("a[href^=http")].forEach(function(link) {
  link.target="_blank"; // or link.setAttribute("target","_blank")
  document.body.appendChild(div);
})
```

More long-winded in case you need to examine each link - it will call anything not on the same server external

```js
// Here I use a template literal backtick to contain newlines and quotes
const text = `There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available,

<a href='https://stackoverflow.com/'>stackoverflow</a>

but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humor, or randomized words which 

<a href="/page2">page 2</a>

don't look even slightly believable.
If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text.
All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the`;

const div = document.createElement("div")
div.innerHTML = text;
[...div.querySelectorAll("a[href]")].forEach(function(link) {
  const url = new URL(link.href);
  if (url.hostname != location.hostname) link.target="_blank";
  document.body.appendChild(div);
})
```

Comment: I would be VERY interested in why this is voted down

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing it with regular expression, you can add this HTML to an element and then set the attribute on all links:

```js
const text = '...';
const div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = text;
[...div.querySelectorAll('a[href]')].forEach(a => a.setAttribute('target', '_blank'));
const result = div.innerHTML;
```

And you have the `_blank`-ed HTML in your `result` const.

Comment: You have now changed ALL links in the page

Comment: I'm assuming the OP will be able to customize the selector, as I'm not sure what's external for him.

Comment: He had one external and one internal in the code and only one _blank in the example

Comment: Well, your answer is wrong too then, because the fact the link starts with `http` doesn't mean it's external.

Comment: It is VERY likely correct. If not then he can adapt the second version. Why so defensive

Comment: Many people and libraries generate absolute local links, so I don't see how it's VERY likely.

Comment: Lol, no. Why so defensive?

Comment: They probably found my answer better, so what?

Comment: How. They are identical in functionality. Anyway, my SECOND version is now comparing hostnames to comply with your constructive criticism

Comment: OK bro. Like I said, I didn't downvote, so it's not me to judge.